# jQuery Selector for Select with ID:1

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following select with an unusual ID/Name attribute:

```
<select name="customfield_10021:1" id="customfield_10021:1" class="select cascadingselect-child">
```

This doesn't appear to allow me to select it with:

```
unit = $('#customfield_10021:1 option:selected').text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stzPQ/

```
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 1
```

How can I select this field? I've never even seen this particular syntax before, but it apparently works on submit.

Thanks!

Jared

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. The problem was between the ears, as I was focusing more on the unusual ID/Name attribute than the selector syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Escape the `:` by using `\\`

```
unit2 = $('#customfield_10021\\:1 option:selected').text();
```

**[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/stzPQ/1/)**

Or you can use `document.getElementById("customfield_10021:1")` as the context for your selector.

```
var s = document.getElementById("customfield_10021:1");
unit2 = $('option:selected', s).text();
```

Answer (score 4):

You should escape the colon, so do this:

```
$("#customfield_10021\\:1")
```

You'd have:

```
unit = $('#customfield_10021\\:1 option:selected').text();
```

That's because the colon is a special caracter, and needs to be escaped with backslash.
Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Escape the colon:

```
unit = $('#customfield_10021\\:1 option:selected').text();
```

See the [jQuery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F).

---

Instead of using `option:selected` you might want to just use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val) to get the value of the `<select>`:

```
unit = $('#customfield_10021\\:1').val();
```

Comment: No, I need the text; the value is an index for a text value.

Comment: Okay, just wanted to make sure you weren't overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
unit = $('#customfield_10021\\:1 option:selected').text();
```

The `:` is normally used for pseudo selectors, and the backslash needs to be doubled up in the string literal.

For the avoidance of doubt, the colon character [**is legal**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/types.html#type-name) in ID and Name attributes.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$('[id="customfield_10021:1"] option:selected').text()
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/stzPQ/2/

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I suppose that would eliminate the colon being interpreted as a selector.

Comment: @Jared Yes I believe so. The quotes inside the attribute selector ensure that the string is indeed a name, and not another selector.

Answer (score 1):

I think that works:

```
unit = $("#customfield_10021\\:1 option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a colon is used to deliminate a pseudo class, just as you do with `option:selected` you will have to remove the colon from the id of your element:

```
<select name="customfield_10021_1" id="customfield_10021_1" class="select cascadingselect-child">
```

This is because jQuery is trying to use `#customfield_10021:1` as id = `customfield_10021` with a pseudo class of `1` which doesn't exist, thus the error.

Comment: Right! The only problem is I can't remove the colon (this is a custom field in a JIRA system).

Comment: Then you will have to escape the colon as others have suggested.

Comment: This answer is wrong - he will **not** have to remove the colon.  He just has to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in JSF is to prevent the form name from prepending each id.

This can be done with the prependId="false" in the form tag :

```
            <h:form id="gestion_clefs" prependId="false">
```