# What could make jQuery cannot get dom by its id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

When i use

```
alert(j(this).attr("id"));
```

I can see the pop up window shows up `_denominations[3].id.denominationId`

but when i call

```
alert(j('#_denominations[3].id.denominationId').attr("id"));
```

The pop up window shows me `'undefined'`, the actual html DOM is looks like this:

```
<div class="form-field">
    <select id="_denominations[3].id.denominationId" class="removableDenom" name="denominations[3].id.denominationId">
</div>
```

So what chance could possibly make `undefined` pop up happens

Comment: My initial thought is you can't have those periods and brackets. Maybe.

Comment: I thought something about [this was familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899881/jquery-selector-for-select-with-id1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try escaping the periods and brackets in the ID value itself. So your value:

```
'#_denominations[3].id.denominationId'
```

Becomes

```
'#_denominations\\[3\\]\\.id\\.denominationId'
```

It's likely that jQuery is confusing these with classes and attribute selectors.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/ZUMna/

Comment: You need double-slashes (`\\.`) when escaping selectors.

Comment: @Juhana, Yeah, that was the answer to my [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899881/jquery-selector-for-select-with-id1) too.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson Thank you, but can `j('#'+obj.attr('id')).attr('id') `work without escaping?

Comment: @Dreamer Yes, but what's the point? `obj` is already the object you want, why select it again?

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson I try to extract the index of one objects id and find another object by using the index and the id pattern.

Comment: @Dreamer A few resources can be found online that provide functions to escape jQuery selectors. A couple would be that of [Alexandre Giannini](http://alexandregiannini.blogspot.com/2011/05/escaping-strings-for-jquery-selectors.html), and another by [Mattman](http://totaldev.com/content/escaping-characters-get-valid-jquery-id).

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson thank you for the resource, ticket closed :)

Answer (score 3):

you need to escape the special characters in ID..that is `[`,`]`,`.`.... since jquery takes `[]` as attribute selector and `.` as class selector..

try this

```
alert(j('#_denominations\\[3\\]\\.id\\.denominationId').attr("id"));
```

Comment: Except you need to escape twice, once for the JS string and once for jQuery selector.

Comment: oooo yes.. thank u .. :).. updated..

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is assuming those `[]` are an attribute selector, not part of the ID; [special characters](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DSelectors%26redirect%3Dno) must be escaped. `[]` [aren't actually allowed](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name) in HTML ids before HTML5, which could cause you other problems down the road - I've seen document.getElementById fail because the ID started with a number, for example, even with an HTML5 doctype, in an older browser.

Comment: Brackets are allowed in HTML5 (you linked to HTML4 spec) and the periods must also be escaped.

Comment: No reason for a negative on this, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

another shortcut .

```
j('[id="_denominations[3].id.denominationId"]')
```

Comment: This will work, but it's very slow compared to straight-up id selection because jQuery has to traverse every element on the page instead of using the native `getElementById()`.

Comment: Functional, but it defeats Sizzle's optimization of ID lookups, so it become a performance issue on large pages.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you simplify your `id` and `name` attributes.

The following is from the HTML4 documentation and may differ for different versions of HTML:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

`ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").`

Personally I only ever use alphanumeric, hyphen and underscore characters. I try to keep them short and semantic. This makes it easier not only for myself, but any other developers who might work with my code.

Comment: That's HTML 4. Brackets are allowed in HTML5. Anyway this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: It may not answer the question. However if the code was written to good standard in the first place the question would not have needed asking.